# How to Load local images in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am just starting with **AngulerJs** and I want to load a image from a sub-folder.

This is my controller code:.

```
$scope.img_source = "../WebContent/Welcom2Iquote.gif";
```

This is the code in my `index.html`:

```
<img ng-src="{{img_source}}"/>
```

Comment: code is ok.  whats problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the image tag as you used to place image for normal html images

```
<img ng-src="../assets/img/{{img_source}}" alt="img_source" title="img_source">
```

Comment: i have edited the correct way to implement image via ng-src

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$scope.img_source = "../WebContent/Welcom2Iquote.gif";
```

if this your scope variable of the image path you can bind the image like below in your html using ng-src

```
<img ng-src="{{ img_source }}" />
```

Comment: @Satyabrat Mahali did you fix your problem??

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the angular-cli, you should have an `assets` folder in your solution.
Drop in the image you want to load, into this folder.

Now on the `whatever-component.html` page insert this line
`<img src="assets/{{img_source}}" alt="img_source" title="img_source">`

The `{{}}` requires you to define the `img_source` in the typescript file corresponding to the `whatever-component.html` file.

So define the the name of the picture over there:
`public img_source: string = 'yourpicture.jpg';`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain how this resolves the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Updated